# How to know if my microphone is used or not?

Tags: audio, alsa, pulseaudio, ffmpeg

How can I determine  whether  the  internal  microphone  of  my laptop is used or not in one single command?

**Example:**

The output of the command should be different once a `ffmpeg` capture is run:

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -ac 2 -i plughw:0,0 recording.mp4
```

Comment: [There are AI/neural networks that can approximate sound waves from a video entirely without sound](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FKXOucXB4a8), so I guess block your webcam as well with some tape, perhaps. And oh, there's a research paper on [guessing what you typed from keyboard sounds](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2005/09/snooping_on_tex.html), it's not very accurate, but it's real stuff. By the way, if you happen to live in a place with walls, bad news.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look into `/proc/asound/card0/pcm0p/sub0/status`; it's either

```
closed
```

or something like

```
state: RUNNING
owner_pid   : 6371
trigger_time: 51690.093652120
tstamp      : 0.000000000
delay       : 51156
avail       : 210988
avail_max   : 229376
-----
hw_ptr      : 79916
appl_ptr    : 131072
```

Comment: To expand on this, to check all microphones:
`find /proc/asound -name status -exec grep -v closed {} +`
If there's any output, a microphone is in use. If there's no output, no microphones are in use.
(Possibly the `find` should be narrowed down a bit, but this is at least a starting point!)